# compare rows differences between two workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have issue in comparing rows in between two workbooks. I would like to compare the rows in two workbooks and add the updated data from master workbook to the next blank rows in another workbook. However, my code only keeps copying all the rows instead of only the new rows.

```
Sub test()
  Dim varSheetA As Variant
  Dim varSheetB As Variant
  Dim strRangeToCheck As String
  Dim strRangeToC As String
  Dim iRow As Long
  Dim iRow2 As Long
  Dim iCol As Long
  Dim wbkA As Workbook
  Dim eRow As Long
  Dim cfind As Range
  Dim c As Range
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim i, j, k As Integer
  Dim newarr As String
  Dim existarr As String
  Dim b As Boolean
  Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\mandy\Desktop\fortest.xlsx")
  strRangeToCheck = "A:C"
  strRangeToC = "C:E"
  varSheetA = wbkA.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strRangeToCheck)
  varSheetB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strRangeToC)

  For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
    For iRow2 = LBound(varSheetB, 1) To UBound(varSheetB, 1)
      For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C").Value = wbkA.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A") Then
          If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D").Value = wbkA.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B") Then
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E").Value = wbkA.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C") Then
              If varSheetA(iRow, iCol).EntireRow = varSheetB(iRow, iCol).EntireRow Then
              ' Cells are identical.
              ' Do nothing
              Else
                If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & iRow2).Value = wbkA.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iRow).Value Then
                  b = False
                Else
                  If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & iRow2).Value = wbkA.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & iRow).Value Then
                    b = False
                  Else
                    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & iRow2).Value = wbkA.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & iRow).Value Then
                      b = False
                    Else
                      eRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & eRow & ":E" & eRow).EntireRow = wbkA.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iRow & ":C" & iRow).EntireRow
                      Exit For
                    End If
                  End If
                End If
              End If
            End If
          End If
        End If
      Next
    Next
  Next
  wbkA.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmJeB.jpg)

Comment: Funny: `....Range("A")...` always pops errors for me :(

Comment: Ugh, why did I even open this question. Those cascading end statements are a pythonista's nightmare. In general, you might have better luck deciphering your logic if you could avoid nesting things so deeply (which very well might not be the issue here).

Comment: To make comparison easier, compare the columns as Join(Array(cells(row1,col1),cells(row1,col2),cells(row1,col3),"")

Comment: Does this code actually compile and run?  `varSheetA` is a variant array (3 full columns!) so you can't call `varSheetA(iRow, iCol).EntireRow`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
Sub test()

    Dim WbA As Workbook
    Set WbA = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim WbB As Workbook
    Set WbB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\mandy\Desktop\fortest.xlsx")

    Dim SheetA As Worksheet
    Dim SheetB As Worksheet
    SheetA = WbA.Sheets("Sheet1")
    SheetB = WbB.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim eRowA As Integer
    Dim eRowB As Integer
    eRowA = (SheetA.Cells(SheetA.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) 'Last line with data in Workbook A (ActiveWorkbook)
    eRowB = (SheetB.Cells(SheetB.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)  'Last line with data in Workbook B (Opened Workbook)

    Dim RowA As Integer
    Dim RowB As Integer

    For RowA = 1 To eRowA
        For RowB = 1 To eRowB
            If SheetA.Rows(RowA) = SheetB.Rows(RowB) Then
                'Do nothing
            Else
                SheetB.Rows(RowB).Copy
                SheetA.Rows(eRowA + 1).Paste
            End If
        Next RowB
    Next RowA

    WbB.Close (False)

End Sub
```

This is not tested, but I think it should work. I'll be happy for Feedback.

Comment: This is not necessairy as the new data was already checked, so you won't have to increment eRowA. And I'm not too sure about this but shouldn't this increment itself, as it has to recalculate everytime it gets called??

Comment: The value is set before the loop - no problem if only one row gets copied, but if multiple rows then they'll all go to the same place.

Comment: Hi Kathara, I've tried the code. However, I've had Type mismatch error for the line 'If SheetA.Rows(RowA) = SheetB.Rows(RowB) Then'.

Comment: Hmm.. Ok, try to add .Values after (RowA) and (RowB). If this doesn't work then I'll make another loop, which loops through the columns of one row and compares them...